# How "Max open files" soft and hard limit are set for specific process?

Tags: files, process, limit, file-descriptors, ulimit

I used the `cat /proc/<pid>/limits` command to check the Max open file hard and soft limit, but I want to know how this value will be set and can it be increased or decreased?

Is this value is set in some configuration file?

I tried `ulimit` command, but that is not helpful to set limit of specific process.

```
# ulimit -n 2048
```

But still i am seeing 1024 in

```
# cat /proc/<pid>/limits
..
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
..
```

I know similar questions are asked but, i can't find any better answer.

Comment: the `ulimit` shell built-in can show current limits or set limits for the current process (shell) and all subsequent child processes only.  It can't be used to change limits for already running processes (e.g. system daemons, programs started previously from the current shell or at any time from other shells or started by cron or inetd etc).

Answer (score 4):

If you have the `util-linux` package installed, you set hard and soft limits for a particular process using the `prlimit` command.  To set the soft and hard limits for maximum number of open files to 10 and 20, respectively, for a command `command`, run:

```
prlimit -n10:20 command
```

Arguments for the command can be provided as well:

```
prlimit -n10:20 command arg1 arg2 ...
```

For much more information, see `man prlimit`.

*Note:* unlike many other Unix commands, `prlimit` permits no space between an option and its argument.  Thus `-n10:20` works but `-n 10:20` does not.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a daemon, you can supply `ulimt -n $your_number` in the init script. If it is an already running process and you cannot restart it use `prlimit` [like John1024 proposed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279389/91809).